# Count the license plates possible with 4 letters and 2 digits

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

How many license plates can be made in a system in which each license plate requires
4 letters (in the normal English alphabet) and 2 numbers (from 0 to 9)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How many plates are there if each plate requires only two letters and no numbers?

Comment: The tag [combinatorics](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/combinatorics/info) is more useful for this question than probability since you are asking for a *count* of the number of possible license plates, not the probability of achieving a specific one at random.

Comment: Also:  you should say whether the order is restricted or not.  Some states specify whether a given entry has to be a number or a letter, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The **multiplication principle** of counting can be worded as:

> If you wish to complete a task and you can break it into multiple steps such that:
>
> - Every possible outcome is described by at least one sequence of choices at each step
> - Every possible outcome is described by at most one sequence of choices at each step
> - The *number* of choices at each step is not dependent on the choices picked in previous steps (*though it is allowed for the specific choices available themselves to change*)
>
> then the total number of ways to complete the task is the *product* of the number of choices available at each step.

For example, the number of three digit numbers (where a three digit number is a number made up of three digits where the first digit is not zero) will be $900$.  This can be seen via multiplication principle (step1: pick the first digit: 9 choices, step 2: pick the second digit: 10 choices, step 3: pick the third digit: 10 choices)

For additional example, the number of four digit strings ($0$ is allowed to be first digit of strings) using numbers $0,2,3,4,5,6$ without repetition will be $6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3$ (step 1: pick first number: 6 choices, step 2: pick second number 5 choices since we couldn't pick what we picked in step 1 whatever that happened to be, step 3: 4 choices since we couldn't pick what we picked in either of the first two steps whatever they happened to be, ...)

For your specific example, break up via multiplication principle.

Assuming it must be in the order  Letter, Letter, Letter, Letter, Number, Number

- Pick the first letter
- Pick the second letter
- Pick the third letter
- Pick the fourth letter
- Pick the first number
- Pick the second number

If you want to allow license plates where letters and numbers are jumbled, such as Letter, Number, Letter, Letter, Letter, Number  approach similarly.

- Pick which spaces are used by letters vs numbers
- Pick the first letter
- Pick the second letter
- Pick the third letter
- Pick the fourth letter
- Pick the first number
- Pick the second number

How many options are used at each step?  What does the multiplication principle say about it?

Answer (score 1):

Since four alphabets and two numbers from 0-9 are allowed, the total number of plate numbers will be $$26^4 \times 10^2 = 45697600$$ because repetitions are allowed in plate numbers!!